# Accessing information in Apache Felix metatype file?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `metatype` file in Apache Felix for my OSGi application.

## Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metatype:MetaData xmlns:metatype="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/metatype/v1.0.0">
    <OCD description="BundleMetaData" name="com.osgi.client" id="osgiclient">
        <AD name="Bundle Name"  id="osgiclient-feature" required="true" type="String" default="CUSTOM :: GREETER CLIENT :: BUNDLE"/>
    </OCD>
    <Designate pid="com.osgi.client">
        <Object ocdref="com.osgi.client"/>
    </Designate>
</metatype:MetaData>
```

I want to programatically grab the `Bundle Name` but see:

http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-metatype-service.html

Requires some sort of PID to grab the data:

```
ObjectClassDefinition ocd = information.getObjectClassDefinition(pid, locale);
```

However, I analyze the `information` object and don't see any PIDs. How can I access these attributes from the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [Metatype specification](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.metatype.html) to see how it works and can be used.

The [PID](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.cm.html#i1233800) is a persistent identity that is used as primary key for configuration data in the [Configuration Admin](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.cm.html) service.